# Fixtures in Magento & the eComDev Test Suite (discard one fixture and use a new one)

Tags: php, magento, phpunit, fixtures

I writing a Magento plugin and try to test it with the PHPUnit Testing Integration from http://www.ecomdev.org. Right now I'm trying to test a method which two different sets of config settings but for some reason the second one is never loaded and the first is used again, so the tests which expects the second fixture fails.

Here's the problem reduced to the important lines:

**Modul.php** (Model)

```
<?php
  class MyModule_Module_Model_TestModel extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract {

    protected $sandbox;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->sandbox = $this->getConfigData('sandbox');
    }

    public function getSandboxSetting() {
      return $this->sandbox;
    }
  }
?>
```

**fixture config.yaml**

```
config
  default/payment/modul/sandbox: 0
```

**fixture configSB.yaml**

```
config
  default/payment/modul/sandbox: 1
```

**Modul.php** (Test)

```
<?php
  class MyModule_Module_Test_Model_TestModel extends EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Case {

    public function setUp() {
      parent::setUp();
      $this->object = Mage::getModel('module/testmodel');
    }

    /**
    * @test
    * @loadFixture config
    */        
    public function testCorrectShopSettingsWithoutSandbox() {
      $this->assertEquals('0', $this->object->getSandboxSetting());
    } 

    /**
    * @test
    * @loadFixture configSB
    */     
    public function testCorrectShopSettingsWithSandbox() {
      $this->assertEquals('1', $this->object->getSandboxSetting());
    }

    protected function tearDown() {
      unset($this->object);
      parent::tearDown();
    }
  }
?>
```

Unfortunately the second tests fails, no matter in which order they are performed. Actually the ecomdev test suite should discard the fixtures (I had a look at tearDown() in case.php) but the config data is still there and can't be overwritten. Is there a workaround or is this a problem with Magento / the test suite?

Comment: Why not official magento taf `https://github.com/magento/taf`?

Comment: @Zyava because it is for functional tests based on selenium (e.g. test of html instead of backend logic). EcomDev_PHPUnit tests are oriented on particular units of your functionality (class methods) and not on HTML page output.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that only selenium part of taf was made public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried the latest version from github? We saw some issues related to config with the new Magento version, so in dev branch it was fixed.

Here is branch url:
https://github.com/IvanChepurnyi/EcomDev_PHPUnit/tree/dev

Comment: Yes, I got the latest version, just double checked it. When I tried to just get the output for $this->object->getConfigData('sandbox') in the second test it was again just 0. Putting $this->object = Mage::getModel('module/testmodel') into the tests didn't do the trick either. (Guessed it would help to create the objects after loading the fixtures...)

Comment: @user1230693 What Magento version is used for test cases?

Comment: Magento Version 1.6.1.0 - Just made it work with >> Mage::getConfig()->reinit(); Mage::app()->reinitStores(); << in setUp() together with >> parent::setUp(); <<.

Comment: You also can specify data for the store, i think the issue in that default config doesn't flush store config cache. Try such path in your fixture
`stores/default/payment/modul/sandbox`

Comment: Got the failures again when comparing the sandbox setting the second time, even when it was not the default config. reinit() & reinitStores() slow the testing down, but in the end it works. Thanks for your help, Ivan.

Comment: Will be fixed any in the next version. Please create an issue on github for not forgetting about it :)